# java calculator simple and scientific mode usage of jFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have coded my calculator in simple mode, I have added a button for Scientific Mode too, by clicking on this button it should open a scientific calculator window. Now i want to get idea from you people how to do it ? Should i use two frames for this purpose or something else? Please give an idea.

Comment: *"Should i use two frames for this purpose"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556). *"..or something else?"*  See the plethora of options mentioned in the linked answers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew I have found your discussion very useful, learned much from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always just use two panels and [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).